# What is SharePoint all about?

Tags: 2007

I just want to get some solid understanding of Microsoft Office SharePoint. I am basically an ASP.NET developer but heard from people that if you take a project in SharePoint and think like a developer you will end up with a failed project.

So I want to know how true this is and what SharePoint is all about. To get functional knowledge of the product how should I start? I request all of you to guide me or share some good resources to start with.

Comment: this question has so many answers depending on angle. Hence it should be marked as communituy wiki

Comment: @unknown: You've asked this question several times in different ways already. From what you've written in those questions you have read quite a lot about this topic. Why are the questions you've already asked not helping you?

Comment: Well a little confused I am i guess. Trying to get the idea about it.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint is very often underestimated in its size. There are very, very many areas in the Microsoft Stack which make up a full SharePoint deployment.

There are many resources out there for IT Pros, Developers, Designers & Project Managers.

If you're completely knew to the platform, I'd suggest browsing as much of the Microsoft TechNet areas as possible.

Here's a couple links:

Getting started for IT Pros
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/ee518660.aspx

SharePoint Developer Centre
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx

The main thing to ask at this stage, is what is your particular role in your environment, so we can find you resources which you need.

Comment: Well i just took a position in a banking sector where they have Sharepoint but no application as yet cause its a new bank and they want to come up with HR in first priority. As far as i understand SharePoint that its not a platform to build MIS system in it. I think its a product which we can integrate with MIS system and get things done. 

I think my role would be one man army at this moment and they are expecting that I would come up with a basic system in it and I want to progress in SharePoint to get knowledge and experience being one man army.

Comment: Taking on board Rob's comments, and yes, using SharePoint as a platform to surface information in an already existing MIS is perfect as it has a lot of the tools available to do that. I'd start by building a proof of concept, and report on your findings of building that, and what challenges you came across.

If it will be globally deployed (and it probably will), you will definitely need support in terms of running the system - one-man armies of SharePoint admins are quickly stretched to the limits.

Comment: James & Rob, Thank you so much for your valuable comments. James I would appreciate for your POC and reports...please share if you like..in the mean time if guys have any real system on sharepoint 2007 specifications please share also.

Comment: No problem at all. Unforunately I cannot provide you with any reference documentation at this time due to sensitivity of the information, and I currently don't have the time to anonymize any of the information. Microsoft use a fictional company called "Contoso" in reference implementations of SharePoint, I had once came across a detailed planning & guidance document but I can't remember where I came across it.

Comment: James probably u mean 
http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/akmsft/walkthrough-of-the-contoso-reference-implementation-p--p-developing-sharepoint-applications-guidance

Well I understand the information sensitivity and I would never want such information or project info one is working on :) Actually I just want to dig some info about what we can do with sharepoint..unleash the true power of it so I can plan the application in professional manner. But if u get a hold on such info please share.

Thank you for your replies :)

Answer (score 5):

I want to address the statement that if you think like a developer you will fail. I think a better way to say that is "It is good to understand what SharePoint will do out of the box so that you do not write something that it already does."  SharePoint is a platform, and as a developer you should take advantage of its inherent features as opposed to just writing everything from scratch in ASP.NET and using SharePoint as a host.

It boils down to two things:

1) Understand what the product does out of the box

2) Take advantage of the products features/services

This is true for any platform.  In fact, there are many traditional windows and web developers who never took the time to know .NET and do not take advantage of all of the features in the .NET platform.  As the platform evolves (based on community feedback and breakthroughs in technology), some people continue to write code the way they know how.  This makes upgrades more difficult and often wastes much development time.

Take the SharePoint developer exams as part of your training.  You will learn much by practicing for and taking the exams.  There are threads on SharePointOverflow about how to best prepare for the exams.  That is another good place to start.

Comment: Ok what about requirement gathering and analysis of SharePoint projects? what are the guidelines for it since its not for MIS project.

Comment: oh oh James i just came across a whitepaper "SharePoint Governance Planning for Sample company "Contoso" ..it seems quite interesting.

Comment: If you take a look at http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx, you will get an idea of some of the SharePoint features by edition.  Gather the requirements like you would any IT project, use the SharePoint features where there is overlap and integrate with your line of business systems where necessary.

The key is to not think of it as a SharePoint project.  Rather think of it like you would any other project, and leverage SharePoint where it makes sense.  Don't lead with the product and try to figure out how to make the requirements fit.